# Given $p\in[0,1]$ form a set $\Omega$ and a function $f$ such that $\{f = 1\} = p$ and $\{f = 0\} = 1-p$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Given $p\in[0,1]$ is it always possible to form a set $\Omega$ and a function $f$ such that the expressions below are true?
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{|\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, f(\omega) = 1\}|}{|\Omega|} &= p \\
    \frac{|\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, f(\omega) = 0\}|}{|\Omega|} &= 1-p
\end{align}
$$
Ideally, I would like $\Omega$ to always be finite, but I recon this could be difficult when $p$ is irrational, althogh the fact that one can choose $f$ might actually make this possible.

## Context

I am trying to write down a detailed definition of a Bernoulli random variable and of its distribution using measure theory. I am working "backwards" from the distribution, to figure out all the measurable spaces and functions involved.

- **Bernoulli Distribution**:

  - *Discrete Probability Measure*: Here's the definition of a discrete measure. Let $(\mathsf{E}, \Sigma_\mathsf{E})$ be any measurable space, let $\mathsf{D}\subset\mathsf{E}$ be a countable subset of $\mathsf{E}$. For any $x\in\mathsf{D}$ let $m(x)$ be a positive number, such that $\sum_{x\in\mathsf{D}} m(x) = 1$. Then
    $$
    \eta(\mathsf{A}) = \sum_{x\in\mathsf{D}} m(x) \delta_x(\mathsf{A}) \qquad \mathsf{A}\in\Sigma_\mathsf{E}
    $$
    is a valid probability measure, and we call all distributions of this form discrete probability measures.
  - *Bernoulli Distribution*: This makes me believe that the Bernoulli distribution, for $p\in[0, 1]$ is defined as $\text{Ber}_p:\Sigma_\mathsf{E}\to\{p, 1-p\}$
    $$
    \text{Ber}_p(\mathsf{A}) = \sum_{x\in\{0, 1\}} p^x (1 - p)^{1-x}\delta_x(\mathsf{A})
    $$
    for any measurable set $\mathsf{A}$. The challenge is understanding what sigma algebra these sets come from, i.e. what is $(\mathsf{E}, \Sigma_\mathsf{E})$ in this case? By definition $\{0, 1\}\subset\mathsf{E}$, but there are infinitely many such sets, so one has to choose a sensible one.
  - *Counting Measure*: To try and figure out $(\mathsf{E}, \Sigma_\mathsf{E})$ I tried to think about a dominating measure on the same space. The classical dominating measure is the counting measure
    $$
    d\text{count}(\mathsf{A}) = \begin{cases}
        \text{number of elements in } \mathsf{A} & \text{ if } \mathsf{A} \text{ is finite.} \\
        \infty & \text{ if } \mathsf{A} \text{ if infinite.}.
    \end{cases}
    $$
    This doesn't tell us what $(\mathsf{E}, \Sigma_\mathsf{E})$ is though.
- **Bernoulli Random Variable**: To try and figure this out, I tried thinking about the Bernoulli random variable $X$ that has $\text{Ber}_p$ as its distribution. Of course, the random variable must take values in $\{0, 1\}$, but the domain of this random variable is unclear to me. However, by definition, if $\text{Ber}_p$ is the distribution of a random variable, there must exist another probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma_\Omega, \lambda)$ such that
  $$
  \text{Ber}_p = \lambda\circ X^{-1}
  $$
  These two things combine tell me that $(\mathsf{E}, \Sigma_\mathsf{E}) = (\{0, 1\}, 2^{\{0, 1\}})$, where $2^{\{0, 1\}}$ is the power set of $\{0, 1\}$, since we know the values that $X$ takes. However, I now need to figure out $(\Omega, \Sigma_\Omega, \lambda)$. My guess is that $\lambda$ is the counting measure on some countable measurable set.

Then, I tried to guess that given $p\in[0, 1]$ one would construct $\Omega$ and $X$ so that the expressions in the original question hold.

Comment: What does the notation $|\Omega|$ mean for you? If it means cardinality, then your expression requires that $\Omega$ be finite to even make sense, and then it is possible if and only if $p$ is rational.

Comment: @MW I am happy to assume that $\Omega$ is finite. You're correct, the definition doesn't make sense unless it is finite

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Context? Please take a [tour] and edit accordingly.

Comment: @Mike the context is that I want a detailed description of a Bernoulli random variable and its distribution, using measure theory. I managed to write down the distribution, I think, but I am struggling with the random variable.

Comment: OK, thank you for the clarification. Please edit your post with this though, as the questions are not just for the person asking but for whomever may follow. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike added information about it in my question!

Comment: @Mike Aaah, I've figured it out. One simply sets $([0, 1], 2^{[0, 1]}, \text{Leb})$ and then 
$$
X_p(\omega) = \begin{cases}
    1 & \omega \leq p \\
    0 & \omega > p
\end{cases} \qquad \qquad \forall\, \omega\in[0, 1]
$$
Then automatically $\text{Ber}_p = \text{Leb}\circ X_p^{-1}$

Comment: @Physics_Student  One slight nitpick, in general, your $\sigma$-algebra cannot be all of $2^{[0,1]}$, you have to restrict your attention to Lebesgue measurable sets.  This includes all reasonable sets you can conceive of without doing axiom of choice voodoo, so it should be fine for any purposes you are considering.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, I would need $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Note: this answer was given to an earlier, much simpler version of the question in which it was not immediate the questioner was familiar with measure theory.  I will leave it phrased as is for the benefit of less advanced readers.]

This depends on how you want to define $|\cdot|$.

If you define $|\cdot|$ to give the number of elements in a set (what we call the "cardinality"), then your first equation forces $p$ to be a rational number, since the left hand side is a ratio of two whole numbers.

Moreover, this is the only restriction, as any rational number will work, for if $p=\frac{a}{b}$, then let $\Omega=\{1,2,\cdots,b-1,b\}$ and let

$$f(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1 & \omega\leq a\\
0 & \omega>a\text{.}
\end{cases}
$$

However, if you really want to get the irrational numbers too, you can use the same idea but with a different notion of "size" of a set.  If $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R$, we can define the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) of a set.  Lebesgue measure in general is a somewhat advanced topic but for an interval, the Lebesgue measure is simply its length.

So then you can define $\Omega=[0,1]$, and given any $p\in [0,1]$ you can define
$$f(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1 & \omega\leq p\\
0 & \omega>p\text{.}
\end{cases}
$$

and you get your desired result.